# Deploying ASP.Net MVC 5 application on a server with SSL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, iis-7

I've worked on an ASP.Net MVC 5 application using EF6. The project is ready for deployment and I've been told by the project manager that the project will be deployed on a server with IIS 7.0 using https/SSL. We will be running the server on our premises and the certificate has been purchased from GoDaddy. During development, I've not enabled SSL in Visual Studio project, and no certificate has been imported into Visual Studio.

My question are:

1. Do I have to enable SSL in Visual Studio and import SSL certificate before deployment, or I can publish the project as is, and enable SSL in IIS only?
2. When do we enable SSL in Visual Studio and import SSL certificate into it? My understanding is that it is done during development to enable testing on SSL, but I'm not sure if my understanding is correct.
3. If development has already been finished, is it still necessary to carry out the above scenario (enable SSL in Visual Studio and import SSL certificate in it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle SSL in IIS- this is what my company currently does. You might want to look into the Url Rewrite Module in IIS. This enables your site to handle requests that are sent to http and https both and both types of request both end up forced going over ssl.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought too. But my manager has asked me to look into enabling SSL in Visual Studio and import SSL certificate into it, which I don't understand why, since the development has already finished. I should edit my question i guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it on your server side by using your hosting cPanel/Plesk etc.Simply change all request the type  on both http and https ,if you want to enable only https requests then configure it on only https .For more details how to configure and enable ssl on godaddy kindly view full details on the given link.
[Link](https://pk.godaddy.com/help/adding-an-ssl-certificate-to-a-domain-in-simple-control-panel-2325)

Comment: Thank you for the response. As I said in the question, site will be hosted on our servers on IIS 7.0, and I've access to IIS manager to do URL rewrites.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to configure an SSL web application in IIS Express. 
After publishing SSL web application, just go to IIS Manager, right click on Sites, Add Website and fill in the Bindings section of the wizard like in the picture below (select https, select correct Port number from the SSL url shown in VS and the SSL certificate as well). Then you can browse to the published https web address rather than having to run in debug from VS.

[image]